# Verifying Crowdstrike Webhooks

Tags: python, webhooks

I am attempting to verify webhooks that are sent from CrowdStrike to my python application.

I know the signature is generated using HmacSHA256, and I have the shared secret.

However, I'm not sure what they're hashing to get the signature.
I have tried hashing the body of the webhook with the secret, and it does not work. Are they using some other value as a nonce?

This is what I have tried:

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

body = request.get_data()
secret = my_secret.encode()

hash = hmac.new(
    self.secret,
    self.body,
    hashlib.sha256
).digest()

b64_hash = base64.b64encode(hash).decode()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue this month and it has been agonizing trying to figure out. I have a ticket open with CrowdStrike support that may eventually give a response, but I actually just figured it out. One of the headers sent by CrowdStrike is `X-Cs-Delivery-Timestamp`. Append that to the POST body before calculating the HMAC signature.

Comment: Well done! Good job figuring this out